# How to spring over importing the last row from an excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, sql-server-2008

I am developing a system where I am importing an excel file (.xls) with a lot of numbers. At the last line of the file I have some totals. I would like to spring over importing that last line but I do not really know how to do this. Can anyone help me with some suggestions?

I need to specify that for my import I am using LINQ and OLE DB.

Update:
Here is some code from my import method:

```
public static void ImportToAP(string tenant_vig_id, DateTime date,
          double value, string vig_konto, int building_vig_id)
{
    int build_id = 0;

    var queryBuild = from build in db.Buildings
                     where build.Vig_ID == building_vig_id
                     select build;

    foreach (Building build in queryBuild)
    {
        build_id = build.ID;
    }

    int vig_id = 0;

    var queryVig = from v in db.Vig_Kontos
                   where v.Building_Vig_ID == building_vig_id
                         && v.Konto_number == vig_konto
                   select v;

    foreach Vig_Konto v in queryVig)
    {
        vig_id = v.ID;
    }

    Price price = new Price()
    {
        KontoNr = tenant_vig_id,
        Date = date,
        Value = value,
        vig_konto = vig_konto,
        vig_konto_id = vig_id,
        Building_Vig_ID = building_vig_id,
        Building_id = build_id
    };

    db.Actual_Prices.InsertOnSubmit(price);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The import works fine, but in the end I always get the error:

> "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

The error is because I have empty column I know that, but I do not need to import this column anyway. Sow that is pretty much my question: "What do I need to do in order to spring over the last line of my file when I am importing?"

I will also attach a picture of the last column of my file.
[image]

Comment: Put some code here to make an answer easier than constructing the whole code (which people generally won't do, especially as they will suspect you have done nothing) else this question will likely get closed.

Comment: Yes, I did that!